# How to change fixed num elements in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Hello I am new to spark streaming 
I want to change a fixed num of elements in a dstream and keep the rest as it is.

Lets say we have a DStream[(Int,Int)]

> ((1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0),(7,0),(8,0),(9,0),(10,0))

I want to change three of them preferably the first three but at random is fine.
I want the output stream to be like

> ((1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0),(7,0),(8,0),(9,0),(10,0))

Is that possible with a map or should I be looking for takeSample